# Use VirtualBox to access site on host from guest? the host and guest is linux

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, virtualbox, nat

I'm running VirtualBox on a Ubuntu (host), the VM I’m using is fedora (guest). VirtualBox is setup to use the NAT network adapter, and I'm able to get to the internet.
I use Port Forwarding to access ssh and the rails web server

**port Forwarding Rules**

```
  <NAT>
    <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
    <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
    <Forwarding name="Rule 1" proto="1" hostport="5679" guestport="22"/>
    <Forwarding name="Rule 2" proto="1" hostport="3080" guestport="3000"/>
  </NAT>
```

now I can access internet on guest machine, and I can log to machine using `ssh`
but I cannot access the Rails web server on port 3080.
I tried :

```
localhost:3080
10.0.2.15:3080 #the guest IP
```

what I can do? All I need is SSH and internet connection and open the web site I host on guest machine by Browser in host machine

Comment: have you checked your iptables configuration on both your host and your server?